# How to use valgrind with a function that is actually the expansion of a macro

Tags: c, gcc, macros, valgrind

Let's start with an example, I think this will demonstrate the problem I am dealing with immediately. This is a simple test program, far from realistic but it does illustrate the problem very well

```
 1    #include <stdio.h>
 2    #include <stdlib.h>
 3    
 4    struct first {
 5        int i_value;
 6    };
 7    
 8    struct second {
 9        float f_value;
10    };
11    
12    #define DEFINE_FUNCTION(type, struct_name, field_name)                \
13    void my_ ## type ## _function(struct struct_name *object, type value) \
14    {                                                                     \
15        /* Deliberately read an uninitialized value to make valgrind  */  \
16        /* report the issue                                           */  \
17        if (object->field_name == -1)                                     \
18            return;                                                       \
19        object->field_name = value;                                       \
20    }
21    
22    DEFINE_FUNCTION(int, first, i_value);
23    DEFINE_FUNCTION(float, second, f_value);
24    
25    void
26    my_test_function(struct first *object, int value)
27    {
28        /* Deliberately read an uninitialized value to make valgrind  */
29        /* report the issue                                           */
30        if (object->i_value == -1)
31            return;
32        object->i_value = value;
33    }
34    
35    int
36    main(void)
37    {
38        struct first frst;
39        struct second scnd;
40    
41        my_test_function(&frst, -5);
42        my_int_function(&frst, -2);
43        my_float_function(&scnd, 3.0);
44    
45        return 0;
46    }
```

If you compile this code and use

```
valgrind --show-origins=yes ./compiled-program
```

you will see an ouput like

```
==25304== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==25304== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==25304== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==25304== Command: ./macro-valgrind
==25304== 
==25304== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==25304==    at 0x40056F: my_test_function (macro-valgrind.c:30)
==25304==    by 0x400597: main (macro-valgrind.c:41)
==25304==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==25304==    at 0x40057F: main (macro-valgrind.c:37)
==25304== 
==25304== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==25304==    at 0x40053A: my_float_function (macro-valgrind.c:23)
==25304==    by 0x4005BC: main (macro-valgrind.c:43)
==25304==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==25304==    at 0x40057F: main (macro-valgrind.c:37)
==25304== 
==25304== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==25304==    at 0x400547: my_float_function (macro-valgrind.c:23)
==25304==    by 0x4005BC: main (macro-valgrind.c:43)
==25304==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==25304==    at 0x40057F: main (macro-valgrind.c:37)
==25304== 
==25304== 
==25304== HEAP SUMMARY:
==25304==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25304==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==25304== 
==25304== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==25304== 
==25304== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==25304== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

As you can see in the valgrind output above, the first uninitialized read reported is from the `my_test_function()` function and it displays the exact line where the problem occurred. This way it's fairly easy to fix the code. The other reports are impossible to understand obviously. The best you can do with them is know which function it was, but that's all.

I understand that the generated code is confusing [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org) and that's why my actual question is,

- Is there a way to compile the code with [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/) that can help valgrind understand this kind of functions?

Comment: Stop using macros and trust the compiler to inline? Hand-expand in the important cases just to get the data you need? Microbenchmark just the guts of the macro?

Comment: @bmargulies The macro emulates C++ templates. It has nothing to do with performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say it's unlikely that the feature you seek exists. To understand why, change the code to this:

```
#define DEFINE_FUNCTION(type, struct_name, field_name)                \
void my_ ## type ## _function(struct struct_name *object, type value) \
{                                                                     \
    printf( "%s %d\n", # type, __LINE__ ); \
    printf( "%s %d\n", # type, __LINE__ ); \
}

DEFINE_FUNCTION(int, first, i_value);
DEFINE_FUNCTION(float, second, f_value);

void my_test_function(struct first *object, int value)
{
    printf( "test %d\n", __LINE__ );
    printf( "test %d\n", __LINE__ );
}
```

The output will be

```
test 24
test 25
int 19
int 19
float 20
float 20
```

The point is that the compiler sees `my_int_function` as a single line of code, as if you wrote it like this

```
void my_int_function(struct struct_name *object, type value) { printf( "%s %d\n", "int", __LINE__ ); printf( "%s %d\n", "int", __LINE__ ); }
```

The conversion from multi-line macro to single line of code is performed by the preprocessor, so by the time the compiler gets around to assigning line numbers, your function is already a single line of code.

In fact you can compile with `-E`, and see what the preprocessor did.

For reference, see section ***5.1.1.2 Translation phases*** in the C11 draft specification.

> The precedence among the syntax rules of translation is specified by
>   the following phases.<sup>6)</sup>
>
> 1. Physical source file multibyte characters are mapped, in an implementation- defined manner, to the source character set
>      (introducing new-line characters for end-of-line indicators) if
>      necessary. Trigraph sequences are replaced by corresponding
>      single-character internal representations.
> 2. Each instance of a backslash character () immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to
>      form logical source lines. [...]
>
> 6) Implementations shall behave as if these separate phases occur,
>   even though many are typically folded together in practice. [...]

Comment: I have no idea why it didn't occur to me to run `gcc -E`, and I guess that I wasn't thinking the preprocessor was responsible, but it is responsible.

Answer (score 5):

I solve this style of macro induced debugging problem by:

1/ comment out standard library / third party #includes

2/ pass through gcc -E -C -P, which expands the macros

3/ put the #includes back

4/ pass through clang-format, which breaks up the very long lines

5/ compile with debugging information

The program is just the same as before, but gdb and valgrind refer to the expanded source. It's then reasonably easy to find the bug, then trace it back to the original source using a diff tool.

The above sounds like a pain, but steps 1 through 4 are just as scriptable as step 5, so the actual overhead during development is minimal. The reason this isn't my default is that jump to error in an ide takes me to the generated code, which is usually irritating.

Comment: This is indeed a lot of trouble. Perhaps it would be easier to find the bug by understanding why the code is wrong.

Comment: It was tedious to write the first time, but now it's just another build target. `make expand`. Useful for working out how macros interact too.